# Ruby on Rails Cloudinary error: Missing service adapter for "Cloudinary"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, cloudinary

I am having an issue with Cloudinary.
When I try to upload a photo via the update form, I get an error on the edit page:

```
RuntimeError in ProductsController#update
Missing service adapter for "Cloudinary"
Exception Causes
LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_storage/service/cloudinary_service
```

Im my Gemfile I have `gem 'cloudinary'`. And in the `Gemfile.lock` I have `cloudinary (1.2.4)`

I also ran:

```
rails active_storage:install
rails db:migrate
```

If I use the helper `Cloudinary::Uploader.upload()` in `rails c` it works. But in the form it does not work.

### storage.yml

```
cloudinary:
  service: Cloudinary
```

### In environments Development and Production I have

```
config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary
```

### This is my form in

```
edit.html.erb
<div class="container">
  <%= simple_form_for(@product) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :category, collection: PRODUCT_CATEGORY, label: "Type" %>
    <%= f.input :price %>
    <%= f.input :photo, as: :file %>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary"%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

### My model

The model also has a field named `filename`

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :photo
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 250 }
  validates :category, presence: true, inclusion: { in: PRODUCT_CATEGORY }
  validates :description, length: { maximum: 500 }
  validates :price, presence: true
  validates :rating, presence: true, inclusion: { in: PRODUCT_RATING }
end
```

### And my controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index]
  before_action :set_product, only: %i[edit update destroy]
  def edit
  end
  def update
    @product.update(product_params)
    redirect_to root_path
  end
  private
  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    authorize @product # For Pundit
  end
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:title, :category, :price, :rating, :photo)
  end
end
```

Comment: It sounds like you may have an older version of the Cloudinary gem which didn't yet support Active Storage. What is the version of the gem you are using? If you update the gem to the latest version do you get the same error?

Comment: Im my `Gemfile` I have `gem 'cloudinary'`. And in the `Gemfile.lock` I have `cloudinary (1.2.4)` @AleksandarKostadinov

Comment: Version 1.2.4 of the Gem is from October 2016 but ActiveStorage was only added in 1.12.0 which is from October 2019. I would recommend upgrading to the latest version which is 1.18.1

Comment: @AleksandarKostadinov, Thank you! I updated the Gemfile to gem 'cloudinary', '~> 1.18.1' and now in the Gemfile.lock I have cloudinary (1.18.1), and now it works. Do you now why bundle was installing an holder version?